# while(true) loop without break

Tags: java, android, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am quite new to Java programming. For now I am studying source code of an android app called Evercam. However, I have a problem understanding a part of the code which involves while(true) loop.

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
while (true)
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] responseMessageByteArray = new byte[4000];
        DatagramPacket datagramPacketRecieve = new DatagramPacket(responseMessageByteArray, responseMessageByteArray.length);
        datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacketRecieve);
        String responseMessage = new String(datagramPacketRecieve.getData());
        EvercamDiscover.printLogMessage("\nResponse Message:\n" + responseMessage);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(responseMessage);
        InputNode localInputNode = NodeBuilder.read(stringReader);
        EnvelopeProbeMatches localEnvelopeProbeMatches = (EnvelopeProbeMatches)(new Persister()).read(EnvelopeProbeMatches.class, localInputNode);
        if (localEnvelopeProbeMatches.BodyProbeMatches.ProbeMatches.listProbeMatches.size() > 0)
        {
            ProbeMatch localProbeMatch = (ProbeMatch) localEnvelopeProbeMatches.BodyProbeMatches.ProbeMatches.listProbeMatches.get(0);
            if (uuidArrayList.contains(localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address))
            {
                EvercamDiscover.printLogMessage("ONVIFDiscovery: Address " + localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address + " already added");
            }
            else
            {
                uuidArrayList.add(localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address);
                DiscoveredCamera discoveredCamera = getCameraFromProbeMatch(localProbeMatch);
                if (discoveredCamera.hasValidIpv4Address())
                {
                    this.onActiveOnvifDevice(discoveredCamera);
                    cameraList.add(discoveredCamera);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't this create an infinite loop? My fundamentals in Java isn't strong, so I would be so grateful if anyone can tell in in what instances will a `while(true){//codes}` actually exits without any **break** or does it **ever** exit??

---

**EDIT**

My bad for actually extracting this snippet from **decompiling** directly from the android project files. I did not know that it would be different, and then again, I know very little. Here is the original [code](https://github.com/evercam/evercam-discovery-java/blob/master/src/io/evercam/network/onvif/OnvifDiscovery.java):

```
    public ArrayList<DiscoveredCamera> probe() {
ArrayList<DiscoveredCamera> cameraList = new ArrayList<DiscoveredCamera>();

try {
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    datagramSocket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
    InetAddress multicastAddress = InetAddress.getByName(PROBE_IP);

    if (multicastAddress == null) {
    // System.out.println("InetAddress.getByName() for multicast returns null");
    return cameraList;
    }

    // Send the UDP probe message
    String soapMessage = getProbeSoapMessage();
    // System.out.println(soapMessage);
    byte[] soapMessageByteArray = soapMessage.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket datagramPacketSend = new DatagramPacket(
        soapMessageByteArray, soapMessageByteArray.length,
        multicastAddress, PROBE_PORT);
    datagramSocket.send(datagramPacketSend);

    ArrayList<String> uuidArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true) {
    // System.out.println("Receiving...");
    byte[] responseMessageByteArray = new byte[4000];
    DatagramPacket datagramPacketRecieve = new DatagramPacket(
        responseMessageByteArray,
        responseMessageByteArray.length);
    datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacketRecieve);

    String responseMessage = new String(
        datagramPacketRecieve.getData());

    EvercamDiscover.printLogMessage("\nResponse Message:\n"
        + responseMessage);

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(responseMessage);
    InputNode localInputNode = NodeBuilder.read(stringReader);
    EnvelopeProbeMatches localEnvelopeProbeMatches = new Persister()
        .read(EnvelopeProbeMatches.class, localInputNode);
    if (localEnvelopeProbeMatches.BodyProbeMatches.ProbeMatches.listProbeMatches
        .size() <= 0) {
        continue;
    }

    ProbeMatch localProbeMatch = localEnvelopeProbeMatches.BodyProbeMatches.ProbeMatches.listProbeMatches
        .get(0);
    // EvercamDiscover.printLogMessage("Probe matches with UUID:\n"
    // +
    // localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address + " URL: " +
    // localProbeMatch.XAddrs);
    if (uuidArrayList
        .contains(localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address)) {
        EvercamDiscover.printLogMessage("ONVIFDiscovery: Address "
            + localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address
            + " already added");
        continue;
    }
    uuidArrayList.add(localProbeMatch.EndpointReference.Address);
    DiscoveredCamera discoveredCamera = getCameraFromProbeMatch(localProbeMatch);

    if (discoveredCamera.hasValidIpv4Address()) {
        onActiveOnvifDevice(discoveredCamera);
        cameraList.add(discoveredCamera);
    }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ONVIF timeout. Don't print anything.
}
```

Turns out there is continue statement in the actual code. Thank you so much for the response, I will remember that de-compiled classes should not be depended on.

Comment: did you execute the code and try it out?

Comment: The doubly-nested `while(true)` loops seem redundant - just one would do.

Comment: That does looks a bit shady.

Comment: basically there are 5 things that stop a loop execution: `break`, an exception, `return`, `System.exit` and loop condition.

Comment: Yes this will create infinite loop

Comment: I wonder if there might be some context missing here: there could be a surrounding try/catch, which is the mechanism by which the loop is expected to break.

Comment: There could be an exception from one of these methods. But otherwise the loop won't exit.

Comment: @daisura99 can you provide a link to the full code?

Comment: @ParkerHalo And `continue` to an outer scope.

Comment: @AndyTurner hey. here it is.. https://github.com/evercam/evercam-discovery-java

sorry i accidentally pressed enter.

https://github.com/evercam/evercam-discovery-java/blob/master/src/io/evercam/network/onvif/OnvifDiscovery.java

It looks different compared to the snippet as I have actually extracted the snippet by decompiling the android application from 
https://github.com/evercam/evercam-android

Comment: @daisura99 no, a link to the *specific code*. I don't want to hunt in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *looks* like an infinite loop. To be absolutely sure, you would have to statically read every statement and follow invoked methods to see if any possible invocations like `Activity#finish()` or `Service#stopSelf()` exists which would finish the currently running activity, effectively breaking the loop.

Another possibility is that the code is intended to be running in an infinite loop as a background thread service, and some other component would have an option to kill that service when it reaches a certain condition. For example, it could be part of a `Runnable` class and executed in a thread pool, and when a timeout exists, the pool is shut down.

Comment: I agree, and with a proper context, like where this code is being called, we could know for sure.

Comment: thanks! you actually helped me to understand more about the Runnable class of its timeout behavior and listing out the many possibilities.

Comment: @daisura99 `Runnable` is an interface, not a class, and as such it has no specific behaviour.

Comment: @daisura99 Indeed as m0skit0 said, `Runnable` does not have a timeout behavior as it only defines an interface to be implemented by a class running in a thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html. The timeout and such are higher level details in the application.

Comment: thanks for the correction and tolerating with my shallowness. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

the only possible way to exit from while loop is if one of the methods being called in loop throws exception. check code of these methods for exception or share it here

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loops without any breaks could be useful for a **Service running in background**.

You create a new Thread doing the service infinitely thanks to a while(true) and when you stop your application you simply kill the process corresponding to the service.